# Something very basic that I have to understand in AJAX

Tags: ajax

Alright, so I started learning AJAX, it's pretty hard for me to understand it but I hope I'll be doing good in the near future. Anyways, My question is, if I do need a server to implement an AJAX code?
Like, if I want to load an XML file I must have a server too, to load the data from it?
My question might be not understandable, that's because I really haven't understood the basic of it.
Thanks :)

Comment: AJAX isn't a language in itself but a way to communicate with a server. You request PHP, Python, Ruby scripts etc. using AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you need a server implement an ajax code. You need server even for normal html files (if you're not using localhost and file:// protocol)

Comment: I see, do I need to open ports to be able to do use the localhost?

Comment: Alright, thanks alot. Last question and you'll get my "V" :). After I have a server how can I load the xml file then, where he needs to be located at? Does it matter?

Comment: @EdwardDaker: for example at the same folder as index is

Comment: By saying index you mean that the html code has to be in the same folder as the xml code? hoping for the last question to get answered, thanks alot, you made things more clearly.